# what is the running time of Extracting from a Max Heap?

Tags: database, runtime, heap, performance

I got this homework question

> "James claims that he succeed to implement extracting from a maximum heap (ExtractMax) which takes O((log n)^0.5)
>
> explain why James wrongs

I know that extracting from maximum heap takes O(log n) but how I can prove that James is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap), building a heap can be done in O(n). Now if extracting the maximum could be done in O((log n)^0.5), then it would be possible to sort the entire set in n * O((log n)^0.5) by repeatedly extracting the largest element. This, however is impossible because the lower bound for sorting is n*logn.

Therefore, James's does not exist.

Comment: Correct! With a minor modification: The lower bound for **comparison-sorting** is n*logn. You can radix-sort in O(n).

Comment: Really clever approach but I think it's a bit of overkill

Comment: Radix sort in O(n)? Only if you assume a constant number of different values you want to sort (for instance 2^32). Otherwise it is n * [length of representation], where [length of representation] will be log(n).

Answer (score 1):

@Duh's solution of converting your extraction problem into a sorting problem is actually very creative. It shouldn't be too hard to find some proof that sorting is O(n * log n) and it's very common in the study of algorithms to convert one problem into a different one (for example, all NP-Complete problems are conversions of each other. That's how you prove they are NP-Complete). That said, I think there's a much simpler solution.

You stated it directly in your question: extracting from a binary heap is O(log n). Think about **why** it is O(log n). What is the structure of a binary heap? What actions are required to extract from a binary heap? Why is the worst case log n operations? Are these limits influenced at all by implementation?

Now, remember that there are two parts to James' claim:

1. He can extract in O((log n)^0.5)
2. He is using a binary heap.

Given what you know about binary heaps, can both these claims be true? Why or why not? Is there a contradiction? If so, why is there a contradiction? Finally, think about what this means for James.